# can the tsoutliers package be applied on non-stationary time series and standardized level residuals?

Tags: stationarity, change-point

can the tsoutliers package be applied to standardized level residuals to obtain better locations of changepoints or is the package applicable only on the original time series data?

for example i tried applying the package to the original data and obtained:
Outliers:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ejmG.png]

and when I applied the package to the standardized level residuals I got this:
Outliers:
[image]

also, is the package applicable to Non-stationary time series?

Comment: This seems to be an effort to carry on some conversation elsewhere.  It doesn't belong here.

Comment: no there have been a lot of questions asked about the tsoutliers package on stackexchange before and I don't think it is irrelevant here.

Comment: I didn't write that it's irrelevant.  You start off this post as an explicit response to another user, making it look out of place, as if you intended to be replying in a chat room or comment thread elsewhere.  Because its focus is purely on software, it would quickly be closed no matter what.  But if you can formulate it as a statistical question--and there very well could be statistical issues lurking here--then it would be on topic.

Comment: ok sorry about that. I am new here and I could find the package developer's name so i specifically tagged him. I will edit the question

Comment: @whuber, i hope you consider my question now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package on any time series as such but it is advised to use it on original time series. Reason is simple. The package is based on the seminal paper by [Chen & Liu (1993)](https://www.istat.it/it/files/2014/06/Joint-Estimation-of-Model-Parameters-and-Outlier-Effects-in-Time-Series.pdf). The title of this paper is ***Joint Estimation*** *of Model Parameters and
Outlier Effects in Time Series*.

The key word here is 'Joint Estimation'. The idea is that outliers influences model selection in ARIMA modeling. So if you use residuals, you have fixed the model and then looking for outliers - ignoring that you may not have chosen the best model due to presence of outliers and thereby not detecting outliers also efficiently.

Even if your model selection is somehow not influenced by outliers, the estimates of coefficients will be affected by not doing a simultaneous estimation. Therefore, it is best to apply `tso` on original time series.

On the question of non-stationary data. Yes you can use `tso` directly on non-stationary data as the package models series as ARIMA (not ARMA). So model selection is based on internal testing for non-stationary as well.

For details see the paper of package vignette.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification! appreciate it.

Comment: if the answer is as per your requirement then please close is by accepting the answer and or upvoting it

Comment: actually i upvoted it but since I am new and have less reputation, my vote isn't visible. i will try closing it.Thank you